# How to get value from HTML <div> by js

Tags: javascript

I want to get 1 from this div tag

```
<div class="h5p-footer-slide-count-current" title="Current slide" aria-hidden="true">1</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelector(".h5p-footer-slide-count-current").innerText

Comment: use .innerHtml https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("h5p-footer-slide-count-current")[0].innerText
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

Link javascript file and in javascript file do this

```
const div = document.getElementsByClassName("h5p-footer-slide-count-current")[0];

console.log(div.innerText); //your div value
```